# Create a code to automatically choose `ts` function's input parameter from the dataset

Tags: r, time-series

Since my dataset has multiple product id with varying start and finish date, I wish to create timeseries corresponding to the product's dates. My sense is using a for loop, but I am unable to execute the code. The code I am using:

```
#sample dataset
 set.seed(354)
    df <- data.frame(Product_Id = rep(1:100, each = 50), 
                         Date = seq(from = as.Date("2006/5/1"), to = as.Date("2011/8/1") , by = "month"), 
                         Sales = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd= 20))
    df <- df[-c(251:256, 301:312, 2551:2562, 2651:2662, 2751:2762), ]

    x <- count(df, vars = Product_Id)

#for assigning individual product's values in df vector
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
      nam <- paste("df", x$vars[i], sep = "")
      assign(nam, df[df[,1] == x$vars[i],])
    }

#to create individual time series for all the products automatically
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
      Var <- get(paste0("df",x$vars[i]))
      Year_val <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(Var$date[1], format="%Y%m%d"), "%Y"))
      Month_val <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(Var$date[1], format="%Y%m%d"), "%m"))
      Series[,i] <- ts(Var$Sales, start = c(Year_val, Month_val),frequency = 12)
    }
```

The error, I am getting is:

```
Error: object 'Series' not found
```

Please suggest how to move ahead or if there is some other way which is more efficient. I have read that `for` loop is not a very elegant method of coding but I am not sure of any other way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to declare the matrix `Series` before the `for` loop

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I have predefined the matrix `Series`. But now, I am getting this error: `Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”`

Comment: It is `var$Date` and not `var$date`

Answer (score 1):

This creates a multivariate zoo object using `yearmon` index class and then converts that to `ts` (or you may just be able to use `z` as is without converting it to `ts` class).

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(df, index = "Date", split = "Product_Id", FUN = as.yearmon)
tt <- as.ts(z)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this function absolutely does what I was looking for!